# React navigation issue with routing to a new path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
 onClick={() => navigate(window.mainurl + "list_task_cat", { replace: true })}
```

I'm trying to navigate a path the math I want go is"tabbiereact/admin/list_task_cat"

but i get a extra previous route withe me like "tabbiereact/admin/create_task_cat/tabbiereact/admin/list_task_cat"

I want to go new route with out having the previous route in the back

the value of window.mainurl is "/tabbiereact/admin/"

Comment: Prefix url with `/` should work,  ```navigate("/tabbiereact/admin/list_task_cat")```

Comment: What is the value of `window.mainurl`?

Comment: the value of window.mainurl is "/tabbiereact/admin/"

Comment: Please double check the value of `window.mainurl`. The way this happens is if the target path hasn't a leading `"/"` character and thus makes the navigation target relative from the current pathname. You say it is `"/tabbiereact/admin/"` but the described behavior says otherwise and is appending `window.mainurl + "list_task_cat"` to the current pathname value instead of using an absolute path target value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
navigate("/" + window.mainurl + "list_task_cat", { replace: true })};
```

If there is nothing other than routing you want to do use the `<Link/>` element.
If you want to call a function that processes information like in a form use onSubmit like in the code below. You could also use onClick.

```
onSubmit={event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    handleSubmit();
    navigate("/" + window.mainurl + "list_task_cat", { replace: true })};
    updateFormState(initialFormState);
}}
```